# What gesture recognizer to use to get continuous tap?

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I want user to tap on screen and hold it, and I want my view controller to receive events when tap started, when it ended.

I tried using `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, but first does not register at all when you hold finger on screen, and second does not register fast taps.

Comment: @rmaddy UILongPressGestureRecognzier is exactly what I need. Can you make an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override `touchesBegan:` and `touchesEnded:` to get what you want or use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.